# Every possible combination in a specific order

Tags: excel, algorithm, sorting, excel-formula

all out of ideas so looking for help. So I have two tables with a single column with ID's 1-29, each ID represents a coworker. I have a 3rd table where I have already created every combination of records from the first 2 tables.

The part that I am struggling with is that I need to order my 3rd tables as follows, say person 1 calls person 2, the ID in table 3 will look like this: '1-2', now I need to make the next record start with 2 and have person 2 call someone who is not person 1 (who has already been called) and have person 1 not be called again until the remaining 28 people are already called as to ensure that everyone gets called at least once before looking through to other combos.

It's a bit hard to explain so I am willing to elaborate if needed.

For those wondering, the purpose of this exercise to to create a bit of "call train" to have everyone check up on everyone else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand this correctly, if you truly want "every possible combination", there are around `28! ~= 10^29` combinations.  This would likely take more storage than the total storage of all computers in the world.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the call chain as follows:

[image]

So in `Stage 2` *1* would call *3* and *2* would call *4* at the same time,etc.  At each stage the number of callers would be double the number of callers from the previous stage.

*(it is possible to map this into a tree structure)*

**EDIT#1:**

I generated the pattern with this small VBA macro:

```
Sub Peak()
    Dim stage As Long, i As Long, j As Long, K As Long

    K = 1
    j = 1

    For stage = 1 To 5
        For i = 1 To j
            Cells(K, 1) = i
            Cells(K, 2) = K + 1
            K = K + 1
        Next i
        j = j * 2
    Next stage
End Sub
```

But a formula-based solution should also be possible.

**EDIT#2:**

In **A1** enter 1
in **B1** enter 2
In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:2)=2*A1,1,1+A1)  and copy downwards.
```

In **B2** enter:

```
=B1+1 and copy downwards
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution, what formulas would I use to get this?

Comment: @MarthaEstrada  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: @MarthaEstrada  See my **EDIT#2** for a pure formula approach. *(no VBA)*

Comment: This has actually been insightful as I am very new to using VBA, however, it unfortunately does not do what I need. I need the last person in column 2 to make the next call in column 1 and so on and so forth, I am not getting that in the result set. I appreciate your time though, so thanks.

Comment: @MarthaEstrada  This is actually a very interesting problem.......if you can update your question with a small snapshot of your desired result, we can make a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that 29 is really good for this because it is prime.

What you do is have each call the next on the first cycle, then each call with a gap of 2 on the second, then a gap of 3, and so on.  That results in this pattern:

```
1 2 ... 29
1 3 5 ... 28
1 4 8 ... 27
.
.
.
1 29 28 ... 2
```

And you have your 28 call trains, using each possible call only once.

Therefore the first record is `1-2`.  The second record is `2-3` and so on.  Until the 29th record is `29-1`.  Then we start gaps of 2 to get `1-3` and so on.

We can even figure out a formula for that.

In general the `n`th record is going to be in the `i = 1 + (n div 29)`th cycle. (I'm using PostgreSQL SQL operators here.  `div` means "division and drop the fraction".) It is the `j = (n mod 29)`th entry in that cycle (`mod` means the remainder after integer division).  Which means that the call starts at `(1 + (j-1)*i) mod 29` and goes to `(1 + j*i) mod 29`.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand sorry.

Comment: @MarthaEstrada Record 1 is `1-2`.  Record 2 is `2-3`.   And so on to record 29 is `29-1`.  Now we go with a gap of 2.  So `1-3`, and so on.

Comment: Ok, so just to confirm I would follow this pattern and execute this manually?

Comment: @MarthaEstrada You can do it manually or work out the formula.  I did most of the figuring of the formula for you already.

Comment: Ah, was on mobile and didn't see the last paragraph of your initial response. Let me try that out. :)